# Sharing a Python Pool within processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Good day,

I have a implementation that looks somewhat like this: Essentially, a multiprocess web crawler

```
pool = Pool()

def worker:
    link = get_url()
    pool.async(worker, args=(link,))

pool.async(worker,args=("www.url.com",))
```

Unfortunately this does not work as it seems the process that the worker is running in can't seem to re-access the original pool and it crashes. Is there any way around this?

Comment: So would this program grow a number of processes in a tree structure? If you're getting multiple links from each top url then you'd need a Pool() at every level.
If you're just going one deep at a time then you could do it without the multiprocessing and just keep going one deeper each time.

Comment: no it wont. it's basically adding a "job" to the same pool is it not? i dont want a pool at every level

Comment: But it looks like you're calling the worker function recursively. Everytime a new worker function starts, it will add to the pool a new worker.

If you get the result of get_url() and return it from your worker, then you have a new link to add to the pool outside of the function.

Comment: the point is that doesnt work anyway

Comment: ah well..i decided to redesign my program. made multiple processes read from data from a common queue instead